# Wat moet ik downloaden?

Tags: installation

Als newbe zie ik even door het bos de bomen niet meer. Ik ga een praktijk opstarten met diensten en ik zoek een CRM waar ik per klant niet alleen hun gegevens kan bewaren, maar ook verslagen van behandelingen enz... Ik kreeg CiviCRM als tip aangeraden. Ik heb me ingeschreven, en wilde gaan downloaden, maar zie dat er verschillende versie's zijn. Ik weet niet goed welke versie het beste past bij wat ik nodig heb, omdat ik zo snel niet kan vinden waar welke downloadknop voor dient. Iemand die kan helpen?

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM werkt achter een website.

Om CiviCRM te gebruiken begin je met het installeren van de website. 
Er zijn 3 website systemen waar CiviCRM mee samenwerkt:

- WordPress
- Drupal
- Joomla

WordPress is een veelgebruikt systeem en redelijk makkelijk te installeren.

CiviCRM zelf is wel lastiger dan het installeren van 1 van die 3 systemen.
Je hebt redelijk wat technische kennis nodig.

Laat maar weten of het lukt of dat je hulp nodig hebt.